# Norm MacDonald said this: “ The perfect joke would be where the setup and punch line were identical”

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain this joke?

I am not a natural English speaker, despite years learning the language, but this phrase makes zero sense to me.

Comment: Note that this sentence itself doesn't need to be interpreted as a joke. It's a commentary on humour (even if the idea might be kind of funny). Also, one thing Norm did well was shaggy dog stories. In this format of joke, you give a setup way out of proportion to the punchline -- a long random story for a cliché or otherwise weak punchline -- and so the real punchline turns out to be the ridiculousness of the setup. :)

Comment: What part of it do you not understand? Is it the vocabulary, the overall meaning, or you just don't see how it's supposed to be funny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'setup' of a joke is the introduction that establishes the premise. In 'story' jokes, the setup may be a narrative. In 'one liners', it may be a question or a short statement.

The 'punchline' in a joke is usually the final line, and it is the funny part of the joke intended to make the audience laugh.

For example:

> **Setup**: Helvetica and Times New Roman walk into a bar.
> **Punchline**: The bartender says "we don’t serve your type."

In the wider quote you are referring to, Norm McDonald said he was "*trying to strip all cleverness from the joke and try and make it as blunt as possible*". So he was trying to write a joke so short and 'blunt' that the setup and the punchline would be the same thing - one statement that contained everything needed to be funny. So, your quote isn't actually a joke in itself - although, ironically, it may have been a sort of setup in itself. Having established the premise that a joke can be a self-contained setup and punchline, he could then go on to make such jokes without the audience expecting the traditional structure of a joke.

Comment: Ah, I see, the joke here is the nonsense that he would strip everything from a joke to the point there is just one thing, that is the setup and the punchline at the same time. The fun is in the probable impossibility of that happening. Thanks, now that makes sense.

Comment: I cannot upvote you, cause my reputation is low. Thanks